# Integration by reduction

Tags: calculus, integration

I have learnt how to integrate by reduction formula but this one seems to give me hell someone to lift me by telling me what to do or simply to solve it.
\begin{equation}
I_n=\int\sec^n x\,dx
\end{equation}

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=10932

Answer (score 2):

Write the integral as
\begin{align}
\int\sec^n x\,dx=\int\sec^{n-2}x\sec^2  x\,dx
\end{align}
Then use integration by parts. Let
\begin{align}
u&=\sec^{n-2}x\\
du&=(n-2)\sec^{n-3}x\sec x\tan x\,dx=(n-2)\sec^{n-2}x\tan x\,dx\\
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
dv&=\sec^{2}x\\
v&=\int\sec^{2}x\,dx=\int\,d(\tan x)=\tan x\\
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\int\sec^{n-2}x\sec^2  x\,dx&=\sec^{n-2}x\tan x-(n-2)\int\tan x\sec^{n-2}x\tan x\,dx\\
&=\sec^{n-2}x\tan x-(n-2)\int\sec^{n-2}x\tan^2x\,dx\\
&=\sec^{n-2}x\tan x-(n-2)\int\sec^{n-2}x(\sec^2 x-1)\,dx\\
&=\sec^{n-2}x\tan x-(n-2)\int\sec^{n}x\,dx+(n-2)\int\sec^{n-2}x\,dx\\
I_n&=\sec^{n-2}x\tan x-(n-2)I_n+(n-2)I_{n-2}\\
I_n+(n-2)I_n&=\sec^{n-2}x\tan x+(n-2)I_{n-2}\\
(n-1)I_n&=\sec^{n-2}x\tan x+(n-2)I_{n-2}\\
I_n&=\frac{\sec^{n-2}x\tan x+(n-2)I_{n-2}}{n-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it as $\sec^{n}(x)=\sec^{n-2}(x)\cdot \sec^{2}(x)$, then use parts.

$u=\sec^{n-2}(x), \;\ dv=\sec^{2}(x)dx, \;\ v=\tan(x), \;\ du=(n-2)\sec^{n-3}(x)\sec(x)\tan(x)dx$